# Tcl access array key from a value declare in another file

Tags: arrays, tcl

I am working on main script that is souring  a file eg
`foo.tcl`
In `foo.tcl` , we have some `array` variable declare
  eg

```
   array set foo {
       "john" "doe"
       "alpha" "beta"
   }
```

In the main script we are trying to access the value using the key of array

```
source foo.tcl
set key "john"
puts ${::foo($key)} ;# can't read "::foo($key)": no such element in array
puts ${::foo(john)} ;# not giving error
```

How to access pass the dynamic key to the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
puts $::foo($key)
```

Within braces, substitution won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use:

```
puts [set ::foo($key)]
```